# Dragging formula down a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to drag down the below formula into a column, however I want the column element to change and increment column by 2 ( skip one column) and the row to remain the same

The formula I have in the first row :

```
=K2*WhiteSpaces!F$16
```

I want the formula in the next cell down to say :

```
=K3*WhiteSpaces!H$16
```

So I want it to skip `Column G` and go to `H`, and the next cell down would be `column J` and skip `I` ..

Is this doable ?

I think maybe the `offset` function would be work , but unable to write it correctly

Comment: Something like `=K2*INDEX(WhiteSpaces!$F$16:$Z$16,,(ROW(A1)*2-1))` - adjust the $Z to whatever column you need.

Comment: Super star thanks it worked !! ...just curious to under stand it , would you mind explaining it  ? Mainly i do not understand the Row(A1) part...

Comment: See my answer, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks alot mate...really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` and a "dynamic" column offset, something like the following. Adjust the `$Z` as needed.

```
=K2*INDEX(WhiteSpaces!$F$16:$Z$16,,(ROW(A1)*2-1))
```

When you first enter the formula, `ROW(A1)*2-1` evaluates to `(1*2)-1`, or `1`. This returns the cell from the first column of `WhiteSpaces!$F$16:$Z$16`, or `F16`.

As you drag down, this becomes `ROW(A2)*2-1` ---> `(2*2)-1` ---> `3`. So the *third* cell in `WhiteSpaces!$F$16:$Z$16` is returned, or `H16`.

Then `ROW(A3)*2-1` ---> `(3*2)-1` ---> `5`---> `J16`, and so on.